# Why is this function-level static variable not thread-safe in AIX and Solaris?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, solaris, aix

I have this simple function:

```
bool foo(const std::string& str)
{
    static const std::string ky[] = { "KeyWord1", "KeyWord2", "KeyWord3" };

    static const std::set<std::string> kySet(ky, ky+ sizeof(ky)/sizeof(ky[0]));

    return kySet.find(str) != kySet.end();
}
```

It basically holds a set of pre-set keywords, and test if a given string is one of the keywords.

I use `static` because I want only one copy of the pre-set variables.

This will run in a multi-thread environment and on different architectures. However, I was told this is only thread-safe on Linux but will break on AIX and Solaris.

I couldn't understand why it would break?

Comment: What is the need for both the array and the set? Is your compiler to old to handle C++11 initializer lists?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it's in a C++03 legacy code base.

Comment: C++03 was not thread safe.

Comment: Aside: you should probably have mentioned c++03 in the question.

Comment: Magic statics are a C++14 feature. Are you a) sure your compiler supports C++14? b) compiling your code as C++14?

Comment: Off: this could be solved in plain C with bsearch

Comment: This could also be resolved by using a class or file static; as these are always created before `main()` is called (and is therefore thread safe); unless one of your statics creates a therad; in which case just stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the 03 standard
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

section 6.7

> An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of
>   other local objects with static storage duration under the same
>   conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically
>   initialize an object with static storage duration in namespace scope
>   (3.6.2). Otherwise such an object is initialized the first time
>   control passes through its declaration; such an object is considered
>   initialized upon the completion of its initialization.

There is no mention of threads; and as such you should consider function statics not thread safe unless the function had been called while single threaded.

Comment: Note: This changed in C++14 with "magic statics" that *are* initialized in a thread safe manner.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's why I quoted the 03 standard - because it's the version that the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

That can only be true if the compiler does not implement the C++ standard.  Otherwise thread-safe dynamic initialization of variables with static storage duration is guaranteed by the standard, see [[stmt.dcl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4).

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. **If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.** [...]

(Emphasis is mine)